# Redux toolkit not initializing state of redux slices

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

This is the code to my `globalContainerStyleSlice.js`

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
  display: 'flex',
  height: '100vh',
  overflowY: 'hidden',
  flexDirection: 'row',
}

export const globalContainerStyleSlice = createSlice({
  name: "globalStyles",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setGlobalContainerStyle: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload
    }
  }
})

export const { setGlobalContainerStyle } = globalContainerStyleSlice.actions

export default globalContainerStyleSlice.reducer
```

As for all the other code, I have gotten it straight from the Redux toolkit quickstart guide, which you can find here: `https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start` The problem, as stated in the title, is that `globalStyles` is not being initialized as `initialState`. I am using NextJS, react-redux, and redux toolkit.

This is how I set up store.js

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import userReducer from './slices/userSlice'
import tasksReducer from './slices/tasksSlice'
import globalContainerStyleReducer from './slices/globalContainerStyleSlice'

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer,
    tasks: tasksReducer,
    globalStyles: globalContainerStyleReducer,
  },
})
```

Comment: How did you create the redux store? What state did you get? Provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)